# Style switcher not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so I'm trying to make a basic style switcher I store which style the user is using in side a mysql db then I echo it out and pick the css but I'm having a problem when I echo it out I echo out pink then I add the .css out of php but says it can't find the css when it's there...

Here is my code

```
<?php
include 'config.php'; 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="items.php_files/<?php echo $battle_get['style'] ; ?>.css" media="screen">
```

Maybe there is a space some were ?? in the echo ?? I echo out the `$battle_get['style']` and get what I need e.g pink then I try and echo it out in side the html with css on the end but does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'";`

and if you are only using style from the user table, just do

`$sql = "SELECT style FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'";`

for the link, use this instead

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="items.php_files/<?php echo trim($battle_get['style']); ?>.css" media="screen">`

Comment: does not work.... The is still a space some were .... Will not pick up the style ....

Comment: What output does it generate? Even though you should still do what Ascherer says - it improves your code nonetheless.

Comment: i have fixed it now with a simple if stament e.g if pink shows this style sheet fi the word is blue  show this 1 and so on ....